# Why is the Function constructor introduced in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

`function` type object can be created by,

- writing a *function statement*(`function myFunction() {}`)
- *function expression*(`x = function(){}`)

which languages like `python` also supports as first class objects.

objects created by above two approaches has implicit member `[[Prototype]]` that inherits common properties and methods that are stored as `Function.prototype`, as shown below

[image]

But Javascript has introduced another approach called *Function constructor*(`myFunction = new Function("")`).

Some argue that, `Function` constructor is introduced to accept code as data(string). But functions are first class in javascript.

So,
Why `Function:function Function(){...}` was introduced in Javascript? What was its significance? Was it introduced mainly to have common properties and methods pointed by `Function.prototype`? so that all `function` type objects inherit those properties and method members?

Comment: all objects must have a prototype. functions are objects, which `Function` inherits from `Object`.

Comment: I think it would help if you explain why you're asking that question.

Comment: How else would you disguise `eval` but by using `new Function("alert('Hello World!');");`? :p

Comment: @Deryck Does my question makes sense to you now?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - Don't you mean [`(new Function("document.write('<scr' + 'ipt>alert(\"Hello World!\");</scr' + 'ipt>');"))();`](http://jsfiddle.net/1v56p0mL/)?!? `:P`

Comment: I think what he's asking is why there is a way to construct it that way in particular.  If so, I recently read something that might help shed some light on the thinking behind it, though it's only an example of what purpose it could possibly hold.  [Enjoy.](http://eloquentjavascript.net/10_modules.html#p_dJLBESQexx) I recommend starting at the beginning though.  PS - I ignored the whole "prototypes are the reason" since it was already mentioned here and you already seem to know that.

Comment: They're slowing turning javascript into Java.

Comment: `Function(string)` should be considered a historical artifact. It is not necessary or recommended except in the most arcane situations.

Answer (score 0):

> Why was `new Function()` introduced in JavaScript?

You'd have to ask the language designer.

This form should be considered a historical artifact. It is not necessary or recommended except in the most arcane situations.

Comment: the members like `apply`, `call`, `bind` are common members to any `function` type object. Can I say, this is one reason why `Function` is introduced? so that all the function type objects can inherit these common members.

Answer (score 0):

From [Prototypal Inheritance in JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html):

*JavaScript itself is conflicted about its prototypal nature. In a prototypal system, objects inherit from objects. JavaScript, however, lacks an operator that performs that operation. Instead it has a new operator, such that*

```
new f()
```

*produces a new object that inherits from*

```
f.prototype
```

*This indirection was intended to make the language seem more familiar to classically trained programmers, but failed to do that.*

*JavaScript's constructor pattern did not appeal to the classical crowd. It also obscured JavaScript's true prototypal nature.*

In contrast, a typical prototypal [inheritance](http://iolanguage.org/scm/io/docs/IoGuide.html#Objects-Inheritance) (the Io language).